# Debug PHP script with Xdebug inside docker container on PhpStorm IDE

Tags: php, docker, command-line-interface, phpstorm, xdebug

Xdebug is configured to work on docker and browser.
But Xdebug not starting when the CLI PHP script is executed.

What am I missing here? How to enable debugger for client php?

**docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

[image]

PHP version info

```
PHP 7.4.22 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 01:30:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.22, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Please state your PHP and most importantly Xdebug versions.

Comment: The thing is: your xdebug config appears to use Xdebug v2 parameters as well as Xdebug v3. But not all of your v2 params have v3 variants. If your Xdebug is v3 (which is most likely) then go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide, update your config and keep only v3 params.

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger Xdebug breakpoints from the terminal, I needed to export some variables before executing the script.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.2/zero-configuration-debugging-cli.html

This commands worked for me:

```
php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes index.php
```

Comment: You don't need to set either client_host or client_port there, as they're the default values.